# Should I comment on my doubts about whether I want to continue my job before signing my contract?

Tags: ethics, contracts, commute

I started working as a developer for a small company (5-6 employees) at ~110 minutes from my home.

This commute make me think if I really want to continue with this job. When I arrive at home I only have time to dine and take a shower after go to sleep again. I'm pretty sure that is not a lifestyle I want at long term and I start to feeling unmotivated.

I like the job, and I will continue if I live at the same city. At the job interview they asked me about the distance, and I said that I would like to relocate there properly. But currently I have no reasons to want to relocate there more than to be closer to the office.

I have been working with them for a while, but due to problems with a lazy subcontracted manager I have not yet signed my contract.

Should I speak with my boss about my doubts before I sign the contract? I'm not sure how long I will want to continue with the job in this conditions, and I don't want to waste their time and resources with me if I finally left the job after a few months.

Maybe if I speak with him he can propose something like working remotely some days, pay my commute costs or just getting me motivated. But my goal isn't to achieve working remotely or a higher salary, I want him to understand me and know their opinion.

Maybe they can offer me something that makes me continue with my job, or maybe not, and then if I decide to left the job, at least there's no resentment between us and we can work together again in the future. I want to be transparent with them.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by saying something? Is there something they can change in your contract (e.g. more pay) to make you more likely to sign?

Comment: @DavidK I think nothing at all, is more an ethical thing. I don't want to left the job suddently and I'm open to proposals that they can make me about the problem. I seek understanding on their part.

Comment: You really need to state the location - the fact that you havent signed your contract has different meanings in different locations, for example in the UK you are bound to a statutory contract with notice periods etc after a given period even though neither you or the employer signed anything.

Comment: @Moo Is a full time, indefinite duration contract in Barcelona, Spain.

Comment: Should you? No way for us to say without knowing what you actually want to accomplish by that. Everything you mention here tells me that you completely screwed up this hiring process and anything you say or do that doesn't involve signing that contract and accepting the commute or relocating will be interpreted by your employer as you simply operating in bad faith. I honestly don't understand your reasoning here. Did you simply not think the consequences of this commute through? And trying to renegotiate because you didn't actually consider the offer and may legally be able to do so? Oh boy...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was going to live with my partner but we're not together anymore, and a little room in a shared apartment would cost me half of my salary, and I don't want to pay that to live in worse conditions than in my house, in which I don't have to pay rent..

Comment: @Lilienthal You never made a mistake? Glad for you, really :) But I'm human and young, and in a country where youth unemployment is near 50%, when someone offers you a good job just after finishing your studies is considered a lucky thing, so I obviously accepted.

Comment: @GerardReches Where did I say that I never make mistakes? I'm just pointing out that you made a pretty damn big mistake, which you don't seem to realise as you're being oddly cavalier about the situation.

Comment: You took the job assuming that you would relocate closer to office, so I don't agree that you made a mistake  (even if *you* think so). You took the decision that was right based on the situation at the time. The change of situation now does not retrospectively make your decision a mistake. Nonetheless, personally I think relocating closer to work is generally a good thing to do.

Comment: You also need to take into consideration that you probably need to replace a brand new car with a brand new one every 3-4 years if my calculations are correct. That plus gas must also be taken into consideration when considering cost of moving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're being naive. By coming forward with these doubts you're not being respectful, or ethical, you're simply shooting yourself in the foot. What it really comes down to is this:

> **Do you want the job (as it currently stands), or not?**

If yes, then move, or simply put up with the commute.

If not, start looking for a new job.

There's absolutely no purpose to informing your boss that you're unhappy with the commute. Unless your intention is to potentially get fired, that is.

The most ethical thing you can do is make up your mind about what you want, and act on it (leave, or stick with it). Simply stating *"just so you know, I'm unhappy with the commute"* is liable to cost you your job for no good reason.

---

#### Edit based on OP comments

So the cost of moving is great, yet the commute is very taxing.

Sounds like one way or another you're going to need to act soon. I would start by speaking to your boss and attempting to negotiate telecommuting privileges, or more flexible hours so that the commute is less stressful, and you can avoid rush hour traffic:

> **Flexible schedule conversation:** Boss, as you know I'm currently commuting from X, and it takes me about Y hrs to get here. It would be a great help to me if I could work a more flexible schedule so that I can avoid rush hour traffic. Would you be willing to consider me coming in an hour earlier/later, and leaving at A instead of B?

Of course this might be cold comfort when you're commuting for close to 4 hours a day. Have a sit down with you boss, and discuss the possibility of telecommuting if you think that the company might be open to the suggestion:

> **Telecommuting conversation:** Boss, I was wondering what the company policy on telecommuting is. Would you be willing to consider having me work from home a few days a month? I would be able to focus on my deliverables to a greater degree when I don't have to worry about my drive home ...

, then approach your boss with a request to that effect. But

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrei. Yes, I need to clear my mind, so I will start with this. I already have a flexible schedule, since I can be in the office at any time between 8AM and 8PM, but I move in train and the train schedules do not offer me much freedom. The commute costs are like 10% of my salary, not that much, but not depreciable. I will try the telecommuting conversation when I find a good chance :)

Comment: Is it common for employees to be fired for just stating what makes them unhappy (work related or not)? I am glad I never got to work for such abusive employers, I would have been fired approximately 50 times by now. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Should I tell with my boss about my doubts before I sign the contract? I'm not sure how long I will want to continue with this lifestyle.

Tell your boss that, and your boss is not going to be sure that they want you around either - Congratulations, you have successfully turned your uncertainty into a two-way street.

You wouldn't have asked us your question if you have taken a couple of seconds to put yourself in your boss's shoes. Your boss wants and needs somebody who shows up, unless they have expressed a desire to let you work remotely.

Comment: I'm stuck at the center of that street. I don't want to avoid them to fire me if that's their decission, but also I don't want to left the job if they can do something to improve the situation or if they are OK with my warning advice and still wants to contract me.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Iran so the situation and conditions may vary, but if I were you, I would have a honest discussion with my boss, explaining the whole situation (time of travel, pre-determined relocation and its cancelation, getting unmotivated and ....) and ask for solution. there must be 2 options: 
1. he/she understands you and tries to find a solution that fits you and the company (best case scenario)
2. he/she doesn't agree/understands you or prefer company's interest above your problem. then you can decide better to leave and find a new job or they might fire you (Worst case scenario). 
I read about your country unemployment rate, and i know you value having job and income, but according to your situation, I think it worth a shot. it could lead to a better working condition.

Comment: Thanks Abtin, maybe its not the best answer, but is the most comprehensive with my situation. But probably the others are right when they say that I shouldn't say anything if I'm not sure what I want to achieve with it.